# SEO em site 100% dinamico?

Tags: php, jquery, html, google, seo

Eu nunca desenvolvi um site antes, sempre trabalhei com sistemas, então, estou tendo problemas no que deveria ser a parte mais fácil de desenvolvimento, as páginas HTML.

Estou em fase mediana de desenvolvimento do projeto, que é uma plataforma englobada de ERP, Emissor de NF-e, CRM, App(web) e Site, e só depois de todo esse tempo reparei que o site, seguiu os mesmo moldes das outras features da plataforma, ou seja, ele é 100% dinâmico, isso significa que meu site não possui nenhuma página de fato.

Um exemplo de como um dos elementos da home é construido (o elemento é um banner com jumbotron):

```
    namespace homeView;


class bgAboutJumbotron {

    public static function bg_about_jumbotron($page) {

        $html = '<section class="bg-about-'.$page.'">';
        $html .= self::bg_about_jumbotron_container()['open'];
        $html .= self::bg_about_jumbotron_container_jumbotron($page)['open'];
        $html .= self::bg_about_jumbotron_container_jumbotron($page)['inner'];
        $html .= self::bg_about_jumbotron_container_jumbotron($page)['close'];
        $html .= self::bg_about_jumbotron_container()['close'];
        $html .= '</section>';
        return $html;
    }

    private static function bg_about_jumbotron_container() {

        $html['open'] = '<div class="container">';

        $html['close'] = '</div>';
        return $html;
    }

    private static function bg_about_jumbotron_container_jumbotron($page) {

        $html['open'] = '<div class="jumbotron text-center">';
        $html['inner'] = '<h1><small>';
        $html['inner'] .= \homeModel\bgAboutJumbotron::get_bg_about_jumbotron_text($page);
        $html['inner'] .= '</small></h1>';
        $html['close'] = '</div>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

E todas as requisições para as páginas são feitas em AJAX, e os parâmetros passados pelo método POST.

Nenhum texto que o site exibe está está escrito no HTML, o html puro de tudo é apenas isso (essa é a index):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
?>
<html lang="" class="wide wow-animation">
    <head> 
        <?php
        $head = new \siteModel\headModel;
        echo $head->get_head(true);


        $meta_tags = new \siteModel\local__metaTAGS;
        echo $meta__tags->get_tags(true);

        $favicon = new \siteModel\favicon;
        echo $favicon->get_(true);

        $CSS_packages = new \siteModel\local__cssPackages;
        echo $CSS_packages->get_packages(true);
        ?>
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="15">
        <div class="page text-center">
            <header class="page-head undefined">
                <div class="rd-navbar-wrap header-corporate">
                    <?php
                    $header = new indexView\header;
                    $header->rd_navbar('bg-dark')
                    ?>
                </div>
            </header>
            <main class="page-content">
                <?php
                $home = new indexView\home;
                echo $home->__construct();
                ?>
            </main>
            <footer class="page-foot section-inset-4 bg-dark">
                <?php
            $footer = new indexView\footer;
                echo $footer->__construct();
                ?>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <?php
        $packages = new \siteModel\local__jsPackages;
        echo $packages->get_packages(true);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

O site também, possui uso em larga escala de jQuery, mas não na montagem, apenas nas interações, todas as informações estão armazenadas no BD MySQL e utiliza do composer.

Sabendo que o site está quase pronto feito dessa maneira, o que eu preciso fazer/pesquisar pra ter um melhor desempenho em SEO ?

Qual a forma de fazer o sitemap pra isso ?

Ou é impossível eu ter um bom desempenho em SEO dessa maneira e terei de refazer tudo ?

Comment: O que os robôs dos motores de busca enxergam não é o seu código fonte no servidor, é o HTML obtido quando seu site é acessado. É assim que eles indexam as coisas. O fato de você estar dificultando a própria vida montando apenas HTML dinâmico não ajuda ou atrapalha o seu desempenho em SEO, contanto que o HTML montado esteja bem-formatado e dentro dos padrões de qualidade de cada motor de busca.

Comment: Mas eu indicar apenas uma URL no sitemap para o google traz algum grande prejuízo ? No caso seriam 2 URLs, uma pra cada aplicação pública, as outras não deverão ir para os motores de busca.

Comment: O ideal é você especificar no sitemap todas as suas urls que deveriam aparecer nos critérios de busca orgânica.